# Records not committed in Camel Route

Tags: apache-camel, spring-data-jpa

We have an application that uses Apache Camel and Spring-Data-JPA. We have a scenario where items inserted into the database... disappear. The only good news is that we have an integration test that replicates the behavior.

The Camel route is uses `direct` on it and has the transaction policy of `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED`. The idea is that we send in an object with a property of `status`. And when we change the `status` we are to send the object into a Camel route to record who and when the status was changed. Is this `StatusChange` object that isn't being saved correctly.

Our test creates the object, saves it (which sends it to the route), changes the status, and saves it again. After those two saves, we should have two `StatusChange` objects saved but we only have one. But a second is created. All three of these objects (the original and the 2 `StatusChange` objects) are Spring-Data-JPA objects managed by `JpaRepository` objects.

We have a log statement in the service that creates and saves the `StatusChanges`:

```
  log.debug('Saved StatusChange has ID {}', newStatusChange.id)
```

So after the first one I see:

```
Saved StatusChange has ID 1
```

And the on the re-save:

```
Saved StatusChange has ID 2
```

Good! we have the second! And then I see we change the original:

```
changing  [StatusChange@ab2e250f { id: 1, ... }] status change to STATUS_CHANGED
```

But after the test is done, we only have 1 `StatusChange` object -- the original with `ID:1`. I know this because I have this in the `cleanup` step in my test:

```
  sql.eachRow("select * from StatusChange",{ row->

        println "ID -> ${row['ID']}, Status -> ${row['STATUS']}";
    })
```

And the result is :

```
 ID -> 1, Status -> PENDING
```

I would expect this:

```
ID -> 1, Status -> STATUS_CHANGED
ID -> 2, Status -> PENDING
```

This happens in the test in 2 steps -- so we are in the same test so no rollbacks should happen between the two. So what  could cause it to be persisted the first time and not the second time?

Comment: Can you please share your route? Also, where is your application deployed? Karaf, EAP, Standalone?

Comment: For giggles, toss some logging statements into JPA lifecycle methods  `@PrePersist, @PostPersist, @PreUpdate, @PostUpdate` and `@PreRemove, @PostRemove` for good measure. Ideally they would _not_ shed light on the matter, but if they do, they are gold nuggets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was -- the service that ran after the Camel route was done threw an exception. It was assumed that the transaction was committed, but it was not. So then the transaction was marked as rollback when the exception hit and that is how things disappeared.

The funniest thing -- the exception happened in the service because the transaction hadn't been committed yet. It's a vicious circle.

EDIT: fixed spelling mistake